# preg_match ignores allowed characters

Tags: php, regex

I have following sources encoded in utf8:

1. PHP script
2. MySQL DB connection
3. MySQL tables and fields
4. HTML files

Why is the following code:

```
preg_match("@^[0-9A-ZĄąĆćĘęŁłÓóŻżŹźŃńŚś\-\.\, ]{3,35}$@i", $valuesId)
```

allowing words and expressions like płatność, nieudana proba but won't allow simple expression nieudana próba? There seems to be a problem with Ó, ó characters that preg_match does not want to pass through. I can go on with a word like ćoba or rćoba but próba won't work.

Why would that happen if it is allowed together with ł, ś and ć?

Comment: I suspect Ó and ó being in the "<256" range might be interfering.

Comment: Have you tried adding the unicode modifier, `u`, to go with your `i` modifier?

Comment: Honestly, I've been observing a strange misbehaviour when I use u modifier

Comment: And yeah, I tried it: "@^[0-9A-Za-zĄąĆćĘęŁłÓóŻżŹźŃńŚś\-\,\. ]{3,35}$@iu". It doesn't help.

Comment: I tested your code, and it matches all of the expressions you gave as examples. [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/kO6Fc8). I strongly suspect that you have an encoding problem with MySQL. Try using my example script and let me know whether it matches all values on your system. If it does, then the odds that it is MySQL encoding go up, and I can give you additional information on fixing that.

Comment: Well, still nothing. Gettin' error. I just wonder how MySQLi connection can affect preg_match functionality...

Comment: What error? Are you sure your PHP script is really UTF8-encoded? What editor are you using?

Comment: Notepad++ with default encoding set on UTF8 w/o DOM. And it's my custom error that fires whenever preg_match returns false. Meaning, when the string is out of scope of allowed characters.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** MySQL `utf8` encoding is incorrectly named.

---

I tested your code, and it matches all of the expressions you gave as examples. [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/kO6Fc8). I strongly suspect that you have an encoding problem with MySQL.

Best bet: You really need to force MySQL to use `utf8mb4` encoding, rather than `utf8` encoding. A good, full explanation and tutorial on this is available [in this post by Mathias Bynens](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4). Key points:

- Backup your database before doing anything else!
- You need to modify your database, tables, and text columns by setting the `CHARACTER SET` to `utf8mb4` and `COLLATE` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for each database, each table, and each text column.
- `utf8mb4` uses additional bytes per character, so you may need to change the maximum length of columns and index keys.
- Change all connection, client, and server character sets from `utf8` to `utf8mb4`
- Repair and optimize all tables for safety.